# Service development framework solutions for Windows Phone 7

Tags: frameworks, service, windows-phone-7, thrift

I've been trying to get Thrift to work with WP7, but has put it on hold preliminary.
I'm now looking for other solutions to this and would like to get some feedback on which solution to choose, if any.

Any suggestions is much appreciated, so don't hesitate :)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to hive us a little more detail. Like a link to Thrift would be helpful. Not sure what you are trying to do.

I bing "Thrift" and get a bunch of things (one of which appears to be a commercial service/web site). I bing "thrift api" and get references to an Apache project.

Help us to help you.

Comment: The Apache project is the right one ;) But I got it to work anyhow :)